# Fetching data from a file using Perl

Tags: perl

I have file as:

```
<country=HK>

    TCN=1
    CURR_TYPE="RS"
    PRICE=10
    COMP_NAME="IBM"

    TCN=2
    CURR_TYPE="RS"
    PRICE=200
    COMP_NAME="CTS"

    TCN=3
    CURR_TYPE="RS"
    PRICE=50
    COMP_NAME="TCS"


endHK

<country=JN>

    TCN=1
    CURR_TYPE="YEN"
    PRICE=10
    COMP_NAME="IBM"

    TCN=2
    CURR_TYPE="YEN"
    PRICE=200
    COMP_NAME="CTS"

    TCN=3
    CURR_TYPE="YEN"
    PRICE=50
    COMP_NAME="TCS"

</country=JN>
```

Now I want to retrieve the values from the members in above file using a Perl script.

My Perl script file is:

```
#!perl

open(FH, "<a.txt");
@a=<FH>;
$b=$#a;
for ($n=0;$n<$b;$n++)
{
    if ($a[$n]=~/HK/)
    {
        foreach $_ ( @a[$n..($n+300)])
        {               
            if($_ =~ /endHK/){ exit 0;}
            print $_;
        }
    }
}

close(FH);
```

Please append the code to help me retrieve the data from the above file.

Comment: Have you done anything to attempt this yourself?

Comment: @AvinashGopal add the script you wrote to question's body. Furthermore, do you have two kind of 'end delimiters' for `country`? (ie. endCOUNTRY, </country=COUNTRY>) ?

Comment: I would edit your question to include that code in a nicely formatted way. You usually get more response if you clearly indicate that you have attempted the task yourself - even if the code doesnt work.

Answer (score 5):

The file doesn't look to hard to parse, although the pasted code uses two different closing tags... (`endHK` and `</country=JN>`). A basic recipe for parsing simple data could look like this:

Retrieve the file:

```
use autodie;
open(FILE, '<', 'file.txt');
my @data = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
```

Loop over the contents of it:

```
my (%file, $country);
foreach my $line (@data) {
```

Remove unnecessary characters:

```
chomp $line;
$line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
next unless $line;
```

And build up some data structure:

```
if($line =~ m!^<country=([^>]+)>!) {
    $country = $1;
}
elsif($line =~ m!^([^<=]+)=(.+)$!) {
    my ($key, $value) = ($1, $2);
    $value =~ s/"//g;

    $file{$country}->{$key} = $value;
}
```

Verify the output:

```
print Dumper \%file;
```

This should print something like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'HK' => {
                    'PRICE' => '50',
                    'CURR_TYPE' => 'RS',
                    'COMP_NAME' => 'TCS',
                    'TCN' => '3'
                  },
          'JN' => {
                    'PRICE' => '50',
                    'CURR_TYPE' => 'YEN',
                    'COMP_NAME' => 'TCS',
                    'TCN' => '3'
                  }
        };
```

Also: Have a look at [Config::General](https://metacpan.org/module/Config::General). This module provides a "safer" way of dealing with such data.